Question on gap in proof of Fermat's Last Theorem
I just stumbled upon slides by Kevin Buzzard from 2020. (For context, he is a renowned mathematician who has famously recently begun formalizing the proof of Fermat's last theorem in Lean.) Unfortunately, I did not find a recording of his talk.
Slide 14 caught my attention:
$\hspace{2em}$
This greatly surprised me, since I previously thought that Wiles' fix of the famous gap in his proof was beyond reproach. It is the first time that I am hearing about doubt being cast upon the final 1995 version of his proof.
This leads me to the following questions: how high is our credence in the correctness of the currently published proof of Fermat's last theorem? Is it still based on work by Gross on Hecke operators that is supposedly incomplete, or has this second gap been fixed? If so, how? I would greatly appreciate being pointed in the right direction, as an outsider to this field.

My understanding is that Andrew Wiles himself (perhaps assisted) repaired his own flaw. This took another year. The corrected version has been widely accepted , so there is no reason to have any doubts. And the credits seems to go only to Wiles considering the fame and money he received. If he would not have done his work (almost) alone , this would be strange.

@Peter I am aware of that famous gap; this is explained on the slide. I am specifically asking about the method with which Wiles remedied the gap, because it is based on the incomplete work of Gross, according to Kevin Buzzard. (The famous flaw that needed fixing is not Gross' work, to my understanding. Instead, Gross' work was part of the fix.)
